# Error handling for poor network connection

Tags: perl, mechanize

I am using WWW:Mechanize to connect and navigate a website, however at times my network connection times out and the entire application comes crashing down. I've been researching options, but not sure how to proceed. I am not only looking to prevent the app from crashing, but I need to build in some logic to get around the issue or, mark the item to try later.

Overall, I have a rather large function that walks through the website structure, fills out a couple of fields and then uploads a file. If network is at fault, an issue can occur at any point in time.

Goal: There will be network trouble... so I need to build in error handling to deal with it. If there is a timeout issue at execution of any of the methods, I would like it to retry the operation three times with an incrementing delay. If it is still failing, I would like it to run functions from another perl module I have that resets the NIC and does a few network tests.

So here is what I am thinking...
Option 1: turn off autocheck and then do manual verification each time a mech method is invoked. This would result in a lot of code copy and paste and I would like to avoid this option if possible.

Option 2: Run all the statements in eval blocks throughout the code and then check for status after each one.

Option 3: Have a function that accepts the mech object and action I would like to execute. This would do all error handling in one place and return back the updated mech object so the rest of the application would continue. So for example, instead of executing
$mech->get('thesite');

I would do something like

```
crash();

sub crash {
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0;     Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)', autocheck => '0', timeout=>'200' );
$mech->ssl_opts( verify_hostname => 0);
    my $url = 'https://imaginarynonexist23123123entname.com';
    $mech = &mech_go($mech,"->get($url)");
}

sub mech_go {
my $mech = shift;
my $arg = shift;
my $run ='$mech'.$arg;
eval ( '$run' );
print Dumper ($mech);
}
```

I can't get it to run through, the ->get method never runs. Can you guys help? Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be `eval($run)`.

---

Use

```
mech_go($mech, get => $url);
```

and

```
sub mech_go {
   my $mech = shift;
   my $method = shift;
   for (1..2) {
      my $rv;
      if (eval {
         $rv = $mech->$method(@_)
         1  # No exception
      }) {
         return $rv;
      }
   }

   return $mech->$method(@_);
}
```

Comment: Cool, that did it! Thank you! I can't say that I follow the code though, what does the for loop do? Also, can you tell (or send a link) on how that object is being returned? What's wrong with just returning $mech?

Comment: For loop: You wanted to try three times, so you need a loop.

Comment: Returning $mech: If that's what you want to do, do it, but I don't see why. 1) the caller already has `$mech`, and 2) you'll have no way of getting what the method you called returned.

Comment: Hi Ikegami, thanks, one last question on how you are calling the function. mech_go($mech, get => $url); I haven't seen this before. How would I add more arguments, for example if I had to invoke $mech like $mech->set_fields('name',$name); or like $mech->follow_link ( text => $department) ? Thanks again

Comment: `foo => ...` is just a fancy way of saying `'foo', ...`

Comment: Thanks, so for my other example, I tried to run $mech = &mech_go($mech,'follow_link',"text => $department") but it's not liking it. I do a print $mech->$method($args) (I am pulling in $args in the beginning of sub) and it looks like it should, but I still get a Odd number of elements in hash assignment at . ... or Unknown link-finding parameter "text => 'IT'"

Comment: `mech_go($mech, 'follow_link', 'text', $department)`

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out just a few minutes before your post. Thanks for the help, I now have a much better understanding of how parameters are sent to the first subroutine and how they are sent to the mech object. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post the final code if anyone else needs it.

```
sub mech_go {
   my $mech = shift;
   my $method = shift;

   my $status;
   my $count = 0;
   $mech->{'status'} = 0;
   until ( $mech->{'status'} == 200 || $count == 6 ) {
    print "Count: $count \t $mech->$method(@_)\n";
    eval { $mech->$method(@_) };
    $count++;
    sleep 2;

   if ($mech->{'status'} == 200) {
    return $mech;
   }

   if ($count == 4) {
          vpn->stop_vpn(); #custom module
          print "Looks like VPN crapped out, restarting, waiting for 120 seconds\n";
          sleep 120;
          vpn->start_vpn_main();  #custom module
     } 
  }

if ($count == 5) {
   return 0; #I ran into problems here, so had to adjust this to $mech and do validation on the calling function
   }

return 0;
}
```